# PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog when Updating an Object

Tags: sql, database, jpa, ebean

Good day! I have two objects: `Tag` and `RelatedTag`. The `Tag` can have many `RelatedTag`s (which is also a `Tag`). Saving the `Tag` with its related tags works fine. But when I update the `Tag`, it has an error saying

`[PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.RELATED_TAG(ID)"; SQL statement:\n insert into related_tag (id, tag_id, relationship, related_notes) values (?,?,?,?) [23505-172]]]`

Here is `Tag` model:

```
package models;

import java.util.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.*;

import play.data.Form;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.*;
import play.db.ebean.*;
import play.db.ebean.Model.Finder;
import scala.Int;

@Entity
public class Tag extends Model{

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Required
    @MaxLength(value=100)
    private String name;

    @MaxLength(value=200)
    private String notes;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<RelatedTag> relatedTags = new ArrayList<RelatedTag>();

    public static Finder<Integer, Tag> find = new Finder(Int.class, Tag.class);

    public Tag() {

    }

    public Tag(String name, String notes){
        this.name = name;
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public Tag(int id, String name, String notes, List<RelatedTag> relatedTags) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.notes = notes;
        this.relatedTags = relatedTags;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public List<RelatedTag> getRelatedTags() {
        return relatedTags;
    }

    public void setRelatedTags(List<RelatedTag> relatedTags) {
        this.relatedTags = relatedTags;
    }

    public static List<Tag> all() {
        return find.all();
    }

    public static void create(Tag tag){
        tag.save();
    }

    public static void delete(int id){
        find.ref(id).delete();
    }

    public static void update(int id, Tag tag) {
        tag.update(id); // updates this entity, by specifying the entity ID
    }

    public static boolean exists(Tag newTag) {
        for(Tag allTags : Tag.find.all()) {
            if(allTags.getName().equals(newTag.getName()))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }       

}
```

And here is the `RelatedTag` model:

```
package models;

import java.util.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.*;

import play.data.Form;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.*;
import play.db.ebean.*;
import play.db.ebean.Model.Finder;
import scala.Int;

@Entity
public class RelatedTag extends Model {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String relationship;

    private String relatedNotes;

    public RelatedTag() {}

    public RelatedTag(int id, String relationship, String relatedNotes) {
        this.id = id;
        this.relationship = relationship;
        this.relatedNotes = relatedNotes;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setRelationship(String relationship){
        this.relationship = relationship;
    }

    public void setRelatedNotes(String relatedNotes) {
        this.relatedNotes = relatedNotes;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }


    public String getRelationship(){
        return relationship;
    }

    public String getRelatedNotes() {
        return relatedNotes;
    }

    public static boolean exists(String tagRelated) {
        for(Tag tag : Tag.find.all()) {
            if(tagRelated.equals(tag.getName()))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static RelatedTag findByLabel(String tagRelated, String relation, String relatedNotes) {
        RelatedTag relatedTag = null;
        for(Tag tag : Tag.find.all()) {
            if(tagRelated.equals(tag.getName())) {
                relatedTag = new RelatedTag(tag.getId(), relation, relatedNotes);
            }
        }
        return relatedTag;
    }

    public static Tag findTag(int id) {
        for(Tag tag : Tag.find.all()) {
            if(id == tag.getId()) 
                return tag;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

When I run this (in which I update a `Tag`), the error happens.

```
private static void reciprocate(Tag tag) {
            List<Tag> peers = new ArrayList<Tag>();

            for (RelatedTag rt : tag.getRelatedTags()) {
                if(rt.getRelationship().equals("peer"))
                    peers.add(RelatedTag.findTag(rt.getId()));
            }

        for(RelatedTag rt : tag.getRelatedTags()) {
            int relTemp = 0;
            String relation = new String();
            if (rt.getRelationship().equals("parent"))
                relTemp = 1; 
            if (rt.getRelationship().equals("child"))
                relTemp = 2; 
            if (rt.getRelationship().equals("peer"))
                relTemp = 3; 
            switch(relTemp) {
                case 1: relation = "child"; break;
                case 2: relation = "parent"; break;
                case 3: relation = "peer"; break;
            }

            Tag related = new Tag();
            related = Tag.find.byId(RelatedTag.findTag(rt.getId()).getId());
            List<RelatedTag> available = new ArrayList<RelatedTag>();
            List<String> availableName = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (RelatedTag rt2 : related.getRelatedTags()) {
                availableName.add(RelatedTag.findTag(rt2.getId()).getName());
            }
            if(availableName.contains(tag.getName())) {
                for(RelatedTag rt2 : related.getRelatedTags()) {
                    if(!RelatedTag.findTag(rt2.getId()).getName().equals(tag.getName())) {
                        available.add(rt2);
                    }
                }
            }
            available.add(RelatedTag.findByLabel(
                    tag.getName(), relation,
                    rt.getRelatedNotes()));
            related.setRelatedTags(available);
            related.update(related.getId());    //HERE          
        }
}
```

Please help me figure this out. After the first `rt` has been iterated, there goes the error but it saves its related tag. Thank you very much.

Comment: I see two entities, but no relationship encoded in the entities themselves.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by relationship? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, sorry, your OneToMany relationship is one-way, from tag to RelatedTag; also, your `reciprocate` method seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Thanks. I added a field in `RelatedTag` which is `public Tag tag;` with the annotation `@ManyToOne`. I changed the `relatedTags`'s annotation to `@OneToMany(mappedBy="tag", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)` but it's still not working. As for the `reciprocate`, I really need to do such. And also, error occurs even in a simple update of the tag's name so the `update` really causes such.

Comment: The whole `relation` if/switch at the start of your code? Doesn't do anything, the value is never used, and it's equivalent to `String relation = rt.getRelationship()`.

Comment: The line `related = Tag.find.byId(RelatedTag.findTag(rt.getId()).getId());` also implicates that the IDs of tags and related tags are the one and the same (since you can search for the one based on the other).

Comment: I used `relation` in adding the related tag `available.add(RelatedTag.findByLabel(tag.getName(), relation, rt.getRelatedNotes()));` and it is not equivalent to `rt.getRelationship` because if the relationship is a `parent` then `relation` must be a `child` and vice versa.

Comment: Yes @TassosBassoukos they are just the same since a RelatedTag is also a Tag.

Comment: Is the problem really because of the JPA relationship? I have no problem adding the `Tag` object with various `RelatedTag`s. Only when updating. Thanks.

Comment: See my answer below for the specific issue; however your entities do not model a full graph; You should not model `RelatedTag` as a separate entity, but instead you should model it as a `Relation` entity that has all the extra information for the Tag<->Tag relation (such as relationship type and `relationNotes`).

Answer (score 0):

Your method `RelatedTag#findByLabel` always creates new RelatedTags with the IDs of the Tag class; if you have 2 related tags for the same tag, it will produce 2 related tags with the same ID.

Look into [@GeneratedValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) and `EntityManager#createQuery`.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm checking the tag name's uniqueness in the `reciprocate` method. I "remove" the related tag with the same name as the tag first before adding the latest. `if(!RelatedTag.findTag(rt2.getId()).getName().equals(tag.getName())) { available.add(rt2); }`

Comment: When I changed `related.setRelatedTags(available);` to `related.getRelatedTags().clear();` there is no exception. That means the problem is in setting the new set of related tags. I tried `related.getRelatedTags().clear();` first then `related.setRelatedTags(available);` after but the error is still there. I really need your help, sir. Please and thank you.